# Accessing a stored image resource using Bootstrap in XPages

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

When I call this image from the image resource library:

```
<xp:image url="/UserGroup.png" id="image1"></xp:image>
```

on a page it works fine, but I am trying to use a BootStrap img but this code throws an error and does not load. In XPages how do you access an image resource for a Bootstrap img

```
<img src="/UserGroup.png" >
```

Comment: It looks to be stored in your NSF. The _xp:image_ looks for it in the root of your NSF, whereas the _img_ tag is looking at the root of your server. Try removing the leading _/_.

Comment: Eric - that did it thanks. Also a bit of a difference with the straight bootstrap and XPages.
The page would not compile without a </img> closing the <img tag. In the BootStrap examples the <img does not appear to need the </img

Comment: XPages are marked up in XML, which requires a closing tag or self closing tag ( _<img ... />_ ). HTML spec doesn't require a closing tag to _img_. I'll convert my comment to an answer, which I probably should have done in the first place :-/ (so much for typing on my phone).

Comment: Bill, FYI: there's nothing called a Bootstrap img tag. It's a plain HTML img tag

Comment: Per Henrik - I was just trying to explain where I was using it just incase there were some specific issues . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be stored in your NSF. The *xp:image* looks for it in the root of your NSF, whereas the *img* tag is looking at the root of your server. Try removing the leading */*.